# Why won't JS rotating text animation recognize white spaces

Tags: javascript, animation, whitespace

I am trying to alter this animation [https://codepen.io/FTP-Group/pen/GoEZGZ](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). I would like to display a two word reveal phrase instead of a single word. It is basically not recognizing a space and smooshes the words together (twowords instead of two words). Here is the JS:

```
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;

words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}


function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 2000);
delay(7000);
```

When using a space to separate two words, the animation did not recognize the space as a character. I tried using a non-breaking space, but it just spelled out the code. I am very new to JS and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about adding `.letter{white-space: pre;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What to do**: 
Add `white-space: pre;` to the css rules for `.letter`.

**Explanation**:
`.letter` has `display: inline-block`, and for this and a few other values of `display`, by default the leading and trailing spaces are ignored.

This is also the same reason why a `<div>` element like the following:

```
<div>
   some text here
</div>
```

will be displayed as if it were just `<div>some text here</div>` (unless you set the values of some css properties).

In your case `<span class="letter"> </span>`, was originally displayed just like `<span class="letter"></span>` (i.e. without space).

But if you add `white-space: pre`, then the spaces and new line characters will not be ignored, but will be displayed just like the input.

---

I've copied the code from your codepen here, but I replaced some text and added `.white-space: pre`. Also, your `delay` is undefined so I commented it out.

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;

words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}


function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 2000);
// delay(7000);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -225px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
  white-space: pre;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.42s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.48s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Nachos are</p>
  <p>
    <span class="word wisteria">very tasty.</span>
    <span class="word belize">very good.</span>
    <span class="word pomegranate">very tasty.</span>
    <span class="word green">very good.</span>
    <span class="word midnight">so great.</span>
  </p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just curious, if delay(7000) was not defined, what was the delay affecting and how would one go about defining it?

Comment: The undefined `delay` just shows an error in the console. It has no effect on the animation. Before trying to implement it, you need to know what the "delay" actually refers to. Between `changeWord` calls, or something else? Is it that when `currentWord` reaches the max value (`wordArray.length-1`), it waits before repeating with 0? There are a few different ways to approach it. For example, store the result of setInterval using a variable and clear it when max is reached, and re-start the animation after 7000 ms (store the number 7000 somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is fine. You need to adjust the CSS so that the  with the space character has width even without content. For instance, you could add this minimum width to all the letters:

```css
.letter
{
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

For more control over that specific though, it would make sense to define a new CSS class to manage your `<span>` elements with spaces, and use JS to add that class to any letter span (when you add the other classes) that doesn't have text content:

```css
.space-span
{
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

```js
if(nw[i].innerText === " ")
  nw[i].className = 'letter in space-span';
else
  nw[i].className = 'letter in';
```

Then similar for 'letter out'. One last note: the CSS line `display: inline-block;` is what allows you to set this width on `<span>` elements, so don't remove that or this won't work.

Comment: Part 1 of your solution still didn't recognize the space and created extra space after slimmer characters i and l. I didn't try part 2 or 3 as I noticed a comment above recommending to add .letter{white-space: pre;. This worked, but thanks for the response!